# Simple Maths Riddle 5

Tags: riddle, mathematics, rhyme

Here's a special one for you!

> I am prime, I am composite
>
> Sum my digits and half; I'll be perfect!
>
> Don't multiply them, I won't yield a thing
>
> But don't worry, it's only the beginning!

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hoping this is good

> $2019$

I am prime, I am composite

> Prime as in [beginning](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/prime) and composite as $2019 = 3\cdot673$

Sum my digits and half; I'll be perfect!

> $2 + 0 + 1 + 9 = 12$, then $12/2 = 6$

Don't multiply them, I won't yield a thing

> $2 \cdot 0 \cdot 1 \cdot 9 = 0$

But don't worry, it's only the beginning!

> Happening around the world today!

Comment: This must be the answer!

Comment: Yes, you got it! Prime can also mean importance, and it is so for a new year :)

Comment: Would the wording "Sum my digits and **halve**" be better?

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

Are you

> 1?

I am prime, I am composite

> Some say 1 is prime, some say it is composite

Sum my digits and half; I'll be perfect!

> ? Perfect number? Perhaps not

Don't multiply them, I won't yield a thing

> any n*1 yield n

But don't worry, it's only the beginning!

> beginning of natural numbers

Comment: Nope (1 isn't conventionally a perfect number) ;P

Comment: Technically 1 is neither prime nor composite.

Comment: To note, a "perfect number" is a number whose factors sum to twice that number, or one whose factors (excluding itself) sum to the number itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking it might be

> $39$ 
>  $(3+9)/2=6$, a perfect number as its factors sum to the number itself: $1+2+3=6$ 
>  $3$ is prime and $9$ is composite 
>  Multiplying them won't yield just a thing, it yields $3\times 9=27$ things 
>  I am a bit hung up on this but perhaps $39$ is the beginning of a sequence where these rules hold true (i.e., it's the smallest number produced by these rules). Or perhaps it's the first two of this series: $3^1, 3^2, 3^3, \cdots$

Comment: (3+8)/2 is not 6, but 5.5

Comment: @SPK.z I can't believe I made that mistake. I'll edit.